# Tie Google Sheets cell updating formula to script that runs on demand?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheet with about 300 rows in it. A couple of the columns have formulas like this:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E210),C10,
QUERY(importrange(SheetKey,"SheetName!A:B"),"select Col2 where Col1="&E10,0))
```

What the formulas do:
When an ID number is entered in one cell, the other cell retrieves information from another cell of the row where the ID number is found. You may preview a copy at https://drive.google.com/previewtemplate?id=14yB8lqTdFvszLs7eaJcWQXVPtQcqBUjp4dJqIY_Yfx4&mode=public -- see the "Rabbits_List" tab.

While entering new rows, there seems to be quite a bit of lag, I am guessing because of those formulas.

Is there a way to tie those cells updates to a script, so it can be linked to a button and run on demand?

I am using Google Sheets with the Chrome browser.

Comment: Looks complicated... I would try entering data in another sheet and then paste a whole block in.

Comment: I have done it that way, @Normal Human, and you are right, that works well. I do hope to find a way to accomplish it via script, because my application is used by some not-tech-savvy folks.

Comment: It finally occurred to me, that the solution is to use the offline mode for entering new data. Response time is much faster in offline mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a script that adds two custom menu commands: "Freeze Formulas" and "Unfreeze Formulas". The logic is very simple: `freezeFormulas` replaces every formula in the spreadsheet with text value of the formula, preceded by triple backtick (randomly chosen string that doesn't normally appear in spreadsheets; you can use something else like exotic Unicode characters or private use Unicode codepoints).

The formula `freezeFormulas` finds all cells where the value begins with triple backtick, and restores them to formulas.

````
function freezeFormulas() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  for (var i=0; i<formulas.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<formulas[i].length; j++) {
      if (formulas[i][j]) {
        range.getCell(i+1, j+1).setValue('```'+formulas[i][j]);
      }
    }
  }
}

function unFreezeFormulas() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<values[i].length; j++) {
      if (/^```/.test(values[i][j])) {
        range.getCell(i+1, j+1).setFormula(values[i][j].slice(3));
      }
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var menu = [{name: "Freeze Formulas", functionName: "freezeFormulas"}, {name: "Unfreeze Formulas", functionName: "unFreezeFormulas"}];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
}
````

Comment: The freezeFormulas script posted by Normal Human also works well when linked to a button.

Comment: Another possible solution. When "ok" is selected from dropdown, all the formulas of the corresponding row are converted to values. Example (make a copy to test it): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J50wJ13Z0FSryfelJOMXbYz47Ate_d6bunesL3ki8aU/edit?usp=sharing